# PHP: dynamic default value for functions' parameters

Tags: php, function, parameters, default

I would like to keep options in a Config class, so I don't need to change several (identical) values when changing (e.g.) MySQL database. So far I'm accessing these options like:

```
Config::$credentials["mysql"]["username"]
```

now, I would like to set a "dynamic" default value for a function, but PHP won't let me do something like

```
public function get_single_db_entry($uid, $table=Config::$credentials["mysql"]["table"]) {
    // logic here...
}
```

What I would like to know: Is there any chance to keep default parameters' values dynamic?

Comment: why not use constants for this?

Comment: @llamerr I like the array look ;) (but constants wouldn't work here as well, would they?)

Comment: constants works fine, why not? http://codepad.org/EkLf19Lh

Comment: i also tested this as class constant but you can't have class constant as array, so you need something else, like in answer for example http://codepad.org/GfFvhiOa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not possible this way. But you can render a static default value to it, and in the first line, if the value is unchanged by the caller, you just assign, the dynamic value.

```
public function get_single_db_entry($uid, $table=0) {
    if $table == 0 
      $table = Config::$credentials["mysql"]["table"]
    // logic here...
}
```

A bit workaround, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) in this case, for example:

```
$table = ValueResolver::resolve($table, Config::$credentials["mysql"]["table"]);
```

and don't forget to use namespace `use LapaLabs\ValueResolver\Resolver\ValueResolver;`

There are also ability to typecasting, for example if your variable's value should be `integer`, so use this:

```
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('6 apples', 1); // returns 6
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('There are no apples', 1); // returns 1 (used default value)
```

Check the [docs](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) for more examples